# How to properly use cxml/klacks library with quicklisp (and sbcl)?

Tags: xml, common-lisp, sbcl, quicklisp, asdf

**Overview**
I'm trying to run a simplified version of [this code](https://github.com/dimitri/pubnames/blob/db4f8b6e017d582069dd57ec9dfe6b1f92b730dc/pubnames.lisp), that needs the [`cxml`](https://common-lisp.net/project/cxml/) and [`klacks`](https://common-lisp.net/project/cxml/klacks.html) library for XML parsing. (The concrete code is Chapter 47 of the book ["The Art of Postgresql"](https://theartofpostgresql.com/).)
Since I know very little about (Common) Lisp/ASDF/Quicklisp, I don't know how to properly install the required `cxml`/`klacks` library.

**System**
In case that matters, I'm using `SBCL 1.5.5.debian` under Ubuntu (For the records, I had tried `clisp` previously, but I found that it comes with a very outdated version of ASDF.)

**Steps I did so far**

*In bash:*

`sudo apt-get install cl-cxml`

(Indeed `/usr/share/common-lisp/source/cxml/` and `/usr/share/common-lisp/source/cxml/klacks/` are now present on my system.)

*In sbcl REPL:*

`(ql:quickload :cxml)`

Result: a long error message, whose gist seems to be `Component "cxml/dom" not found`. (Even though `/usr/share/common-lisp/source/cxml/dom` does exist, but I'm not sure it matters.) See complete error message at the end.

`(ql:quickload :klacks)`

Result: another long error, whose gist is `System "klacks" not found` (even though, again, the directory is present on the system).

**Remark**

Using `qucikload` for other libraries works, e.g.:

```
(ql:quickload :postmodern)
(ql:quickload :zip)
(ql:quickload :yason)
```

**Questions**

In short: what is the proper way of getting `cxml` and `klacks` installed on the above system?

Besides the solution to this concrete issue, I'd like to understand a bit better what is going on, in particular:

- Can all dependencies be installed with `quicklisp`, or are there some that support it and some that don't? (And in this case, is `cxml` a dependency that does not support `quicklisp`? How can I know which packages do support it?)
- Does `quciklisp` look at the local installation (i.e. `/usr/share/common-lisp/source/cxml/`) at all, or does it work only from an online repository? (In other words: does it matter that I installed `cl-xml` via apt-get?)
- If it takes the local path into account, then why doesn't it find `cxml/dom` and `cxml/klacks`?
- Since `klacks` is a subpackage of `cxml`, do I need to import it separately or not?
  By browsing the mentioned source code, especially [package.lisp](https://github.com/dimitri/pubnames/blob/db4f8b6e017d582069dd57ec9dfe6b1f92b730dc/package.lisp) and [pubnames.asd](https://github.com/dimitri/pubnames/blob/db4f8b6e017d582069dd57ec9dfe6b1f92b730dc/pubnames.asd), I don't see it explicitly imported. Still it is used in the code, e.g. [here](https://github.com/dimitri/pubnames/blob/db4f8b6e017d582069dd57ec9dfe6b1f92b730dc/pubnames.lisp#L60). So I guess what is needed is to import `cxml` explicitly, and then all subpackages (including `klacks`) get also imported, automatically prefixed with the proper namespace?

**Detailed error messages**

```
* (ql:quickload :cxml)
;;; Checking for wide character support... WARNING: Lisp implementation doesn't use UTF-16, but accepts surrogate code points.
 yes, using code points.
To load "cxml":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    cxml
; Loading "cxml"
;;; Checking for wide character support... WARNING: Lisp implementation doesn't use UTF-16, but accepts surrogate code points.
 yes, using code points.
.
;;; Checking for wide character support... WARNING: Lisp implementation doesn't use UTF-16, but accepts surrogate code points.
 yes, using code points.
;;; Checking for wide character support... WARNING: Lisp implementation doesn't use UTF-16, but accepts surrogate code points.
 yes, using code points.
;;; Building Closure with CHARACTER RUNES
To load "cxml/dom":
  Load 3 ASDF systems:
    closure-common puri trivial-gray-streams
  Install 1 Quicklisp release:
    cxml
; Loading "cxml/dom"
;;; Checking for wide character support... WARNING: Lisp implementation doesn't use UTF-16, but accepts surrogate code points.
 yes, using code points.
.
debugger invoked on a ASDF/FIND-COMPONENT:MISSING-COMPONENT in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {10005504C3}>:
  Component "cxml/dom" not found

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [RETRY                        ] Retry ASDF operation.
  1: [CLEAR-CONFIGURATION-AND-RETRY] Retry ASDF operation after resetting the
                                     configuration.
  2:                                 Retry ASDF operation.
  3:                                 Retry ASDF operation after resetting the
                                     configuration.
  4: [ABORT                        ] Give up on "cxml/dom"
  5:                                 Give up on "cxml"
  6:                                 Exit debugger, returning to top level.

((:METHOD ASDF/OPERATE:OPERATE (SYMBOL T)) ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP "cxml/dom" :VERBOSE NIL) [fast-method]
   error finding frame source: Bogus form-number: the source file has probably
                               changed too much to cope with.
   source: NIL
0]
```

```
* (ql:quickload :klacks)

debugger invoked on a QUICKLISP-CLIENT:SYSTEM-NOT-FOUND in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {10005504C3}>:
  System "klacks" not found

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [CONTINUE] Try again
  1: [ABORT   ] Give up on "klacks"
  2:            Exit debugger, returning to top level.

((LABELS QUICKLISP-CLIENT::RECURSE :IN QUICKLISP-CLIENT::COMPUTE-LOAD-STRATEGY) "klacks")
   source: (CERROR "Try again" 'SYSTEM-NOT-FOUND :NAME NAME)
```

Comment: I suspect strongly your SBCL is too old, and you should try with a current one.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can load other systems, I assume you've gone through setting up quicklisp on your system.

There is no package named "klacks" on quicklisp.

You can check this by running:

```
(ql:system-apropos "klacks")
```

Which outputs:

```
#<SYSTEM cxml-klacks / cxml-20181018-git / quicklisp 2019-03-07>
#<SYSTEM cxml/klacks / cxml-20181018-git / quicklisp 2019-03-07>
#<SYSTEM fxml/klacks / fxml-20181210-git / quicklisp 2019-03-07>
```

So the system you are looking for is `cxml-klacks`

Load it using:

```
(ql:quickload "cxml-klacks")
```

Which loads fine. Output on my system:

```
To load "cxml-klacks":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    cxml-klacks
; Loading "cxml-klacks"
;;; Checking for wide character support... yes, using code points.
;;; Checking for wide character support... yes, using code points.
;;; Building Closure with CHARACTER RUNES

("cxml-klacks")
```

Also, `cxml` loads fine on my system but I'm using Clozure CL, I'm not sure what that error is for you. Try loading `cxml-klacks` and see if that works for you.

You can also try loading `cxml/klacks`, which maybe the package you want.

Comment: Thanks for the hint: `(ql:system-apropos "klacks")` returns the same results as yours (although with newer timestamps), but both `(ql:quickload "cxml-klacks")` and `(ql:quickload "cxml/klacks")` fail (reason seems to be `Component "cxml/klacks" not found`).

Comment: > _I assume you've gone through setting up quicklisp on your system_

Yeah, and with some other packages (like `postmodern`, `zip`, ...) it works fine.

Comment: Think you need to finish installing cxml first. And that is choking on cxml/dom.

Comment: Can you try working with the newest version of sbcl? From the homepage: The most recent version is SBCL 2.0.6, released June 29, 2020.

Answer (score 1):

The most important is that you have installed `quicklisp` in your system.

Follow for that exactly the installations in grey box of [here](https://www.quicklisp.org/beta/#installation).

In short, this is:

```
# in mac:
$ curl -O https://beta.quicklisp.org/quicklisp.lisp
# or in linux do:
$ wget https://beta.quicklisp.org/quicklisp.lisp
# in windows download manually https://beta.quicklisp.org/quicklisp.lisp

# $ curl -O https://beta.quicklisp.org/quicklisp.lisp.asc # this I leave out
# $ gpg --verify quicklisp.lisp.asc quicklisp.lisp

# start SBCL
$ sbcl --load quicklisp.lisp # path to the downloaded quicklisp.lisp!

# in SBCL REPL install quicklisp by:
* (quicklisp-quickstart:install)

# it says:
#   ==== quicklisp installed ====
# 
#     To load a system, use: (ql:quickload "system-name")
# 
#     To find systems, use: (ql:system-apropos "term")# 
# 
#     To load Quicklisp every time you start Lisp, use: (ql:add-to-init-file)
# 
#     For more information, see http://www.quicklisp.org/beta/
# 

# test by installing vecto package:
* (ql:system-apropos "vecto")

; Fetching #<URL "http://beta.quicklisp.org/dist/quicklisp/2010-10-07/systems.txt">
; 45.30KB
==================================================
46,386 bytes in 0.50 seconds (89.70KB/sec)
; Fetching #<URL "http://beta.quicklisp.org/dist/quicklisp/2010-10-07/releases.txt">
; 83.49KB
==================================================
85,490 bytes in 0.53 seconds (157.22KB/sec)
#<SYSTEM cl-vectors / cl-vectors-20101006-git / quicklisp 2010-10-07>
#<SYSTEM lispbuilder-sdl-cl-vectors / lispbuilder-20101006-svn / quicklisp 2010-10-07>
#<SYSTEM lispbuilder-sdl-cl-vectors-examples / lispbuilder-20101006-svn / quicklisp 2010-10-07>
#<SYSTEM lispbuilder-sdl-vecto / lispbuilder-20101006-svn / quicklisp 2010-10-07>
#<SYSTEM lispbuilder-sdl-vecto-examples / lispbuilder-20101006-svn / quicklisp 2010-10-07>
#<SYSTEM static-vectors / static-vectors-20101006-git / quicklisp 2010-10-07>
#<SYSTEM vecto / vecto-1.4.3 / quicklisp 2010-10-07>
NIL

# load it:
* (ql:quickload "vecto")
To load "vecto":
  Install 5 Quicklisp releases:
    cl-vectors salza2 vecto zpb-ttf zpng
; Fetching #<URL "http://beta.quicklisp.org/archive/salza2/2010-10-06/salza2-2.0.7.tgz">
; 14.84KB
==================================================
15,197 bytes in 0.12 seconds (125.77KB/sec)
; Fetching #<URL "http://beta.quicklisp.org/archive/zpng/2010-10-06/zpng-1.2.tgz">
; 38.59KB
==================================================
39,521 bytes in 0.37 seconds (103.47KB/sec)
; Fetching #<URL "http://beta.quicklisp.org/archive/zpb-ttf/2010-10-06/zpb-ttf-1.0.tgz">
; 42.59KB
==================================================
43,611 bytes in 0.39 seconds (110.33KB/sec)
; Fetching #<URL "http://beta.quicklisp.org/archive/cl-vectors/2010-10-06/cl-vectors-20101006-git.tgz">
; 40.40KB
==================================================
41,374 bytes in 0.37 seconds (109.20KB/sec)
; Fetching #<URL "http://beta.quicklisp.org/archive/vecto/2010-10-06/vecto-1.4.3.tgz">
; 75.71KB
==================================================
77,526 bytes in 0.49 seconds (153.57KB/sec)
; Loading "vecto"
..................................................
[package zpb-ttf].................................
[package salza2]..................................
[package zpng]....................................
[package net.tuxee.paths].........................
[package net.tuxee.aa]............................
[package net.tuxee.aa-bin]........................
[package net.tuxee.vectors].......................
[package vecto]........
("vecto")

# highly recommended - do:
* (ql:add-to-init-file)

# this will give:

I will append the following lines to #P"/Users/quicklisp/.sbclrc":

  ;;; The following lines added by ql:add-to-init-file:
  #-quicklisp
  (let ((quicklisp-init (merge-pathnames "quicklisp/setup.lisp"
                                         (user-homedir-pathname))))
    (when (probe-file quicklisp-init)
      (load quicklisp-init)))

Press Enter to continue. # do that!


#P"/Users/quicklisp/.sbclrc"
* (quit)
$
```

The before-last step adds the load command for `setup.lisp` of quicklisp to .sbclrc . Add it to any config file of the implementation you use, e.g. for `clisp` ad it to `~/.clisp` which you create if there is none.

When installing let it install to home folder (`~/quicklisp`).
So that path is `~/quicklisp/setup.lisp`.
In sbcl, you can start quicklisp by `(load "~/quicklisp/setup.lisp")`.
If not added this load command into your `~/.sbclrc` file.

Install/import klacks by:

```
(ql:quickload :cxml)

;; then use it by:
(klacks:<klacks-function> <args>)

;; it is one of the few packages, where you install by another name
;; but then have several names available for sub-packages!
```